# How to find out which text field has been used in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I have the following form :

```
<input name="linkColor" type="text" id="colorpickerField0" >
<input name="linkColor" type="text" id="colorpickerField1" >
<input name="linkColor" type="text" id="colorpickerField2" >
```

In my function below, how may I find out which text field has been invoked. For example, I want to set conditions in the onSubmit function where if #colorpickerField0 then do blah blah, and if #colorpickerField1 THEN do blah blah blah etc etc. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
$('#colorpickerField0, #colorpickerField1, #colorpickerField2').ColorPicker({
    onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
        alert($(this));
        // do this if #Field0
        // statements
        // do this if #Field1
        // statements
        // do this if #Field2
        // statemets

        $(el).val(hex);
        $(el).ColorPickerHide();
    },
    onBeforeShow: function () {
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
    }
})
.bind('keyup', function(){
    $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
});
```

I'm using http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

If I do alert($(this).attr('id')); I get undefined, so I still can't tell which one was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ($(el).attr('id') == 'colorpickerField0') { ...
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {

    var myID = $(this).attr('id');

    if(myID.indexOf('Field0')) {
        // ..
    }
    else if(myID.indexOf('Field1')) {
        // ..
    }
    else if(myID.indexOf('Field2')) {
        // ..
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Guys, thanks for the replies. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. If I alert($(this).attr('id')); I get Undefined on submit. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Its strange since the main outer selector in your question is `$('#colorpickerField0, #colorpickerField1, #colorpickerField2')` - something which matches by id. Also the inputs in your HTML fragment have valid ids.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `el` parameter to your onSubmit function contains the HTMLElement. I think you should be able to `switch($(el).attr('id')) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                alert($(this));
                            if($(this).attr('id') == "colorpickerField0"){

                            }

                            // do this if #Field0
                            // statements
                            // do this if #Field1
                            // statements
                            // do this if #Field2
                            // statemets
  }
[...]
```

and so on for all objects.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `alert($(el).attr("id"));`?